# Save a mouse coorinates after a specific number of seconds

Tags: java, realtime

I have a specific method that saves my mouse x and y coordinates. I want that mouse coordinates be saved by specific time (for example after 1000ms). How I need to do that in Java?
Please add a simple usage example.

```
 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        currentX = e.getX();
        currentY = e.getY();

        if(enemy.onWall() == true){
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                public void run() {
                    saveX = e.getX();
                    saveY = e.getY();
                    enemy.setCont(true);
                    move();
                }
            },100);
            enemy.setOnWall(false);
        }
    }
```

But this code saves mouse coorinates immediately and then waits for 1000ms and I have old coordinates.

Comment: I have just edited my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT

Actually, Timer's schedule method should work in this case - maybe it's running *straight away* because you have 100ms as your delay time instead of 1000 (from your code above that is).

---

If you're working in a multi-threaded environment, then make sure you handle possible concurrency issues.

A possible alternative would be to use `System.nanoTime()`

Declare these variables:

```
long delay = 1000;
long start = 0;
Point temp;
```

In the `mouseMoved` method:

```
    if(enemy.onWall() == true){
        temp = e.getLocation();
        start = System.nanoTime();
        enemy.setOnWall(false);
    }
```

(is enemy.setOnWall(false); supposed to be called after 1000ms?)

And in your game loop:

```
if (start > 0 && (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000 >= delay) {
    saveX = temp.getX();
    saveY = temp.getY();
    enemy.setCont(true);
    move();
    start = 0;
}
```

The "timer" is initiated when you move the mouse and is checked each frame to see if the duration since `start` was set is at least as long as the delay; if it is, the coordinates set at the start should be applied.

Since you move the mouse frequently, you may want to `return` the `mouseMoved` method if a coordinate is already scheduled to be saved.

This way you avoid multiple threads and result in a fairly accurate timed task.

Comment: `nanoTime()` is a good option here since it's more precise and the "downside" that it's from system start instead of Epoch doesn't matter.